# Is it useless to use StringBuilder in the below case?

Tags: java, stringbuilder

I have a case where i need to build a **URL** with key at the end of the url. I need to change the URL by changing different keys.

Is using `StringBuilder` like the below useless as i am converting it back to a `string`

```
//the below line loops for a number of times with strKey changing each time
url = new URL(strUrl.append(strKey).toString());
```

Comment: If you write it as `strUrl + strKey`, java compiler will create the stringbuilders for you.

Comment: I don't think you've given us enough information to help you. Given you're looping, it seems like you're reusing the `strUrl` `StringBuilder`, repeatedly appending to it, so no that doesn't seem pointless. If you used string concatenation, `StringBuilders` would be created and thrown away each time.

Answer (score 1):

It is. Just concatenating the strings here is probably faster (since you're only copying the data once) and clearer.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, and for all modern JDKs (Java 1.5+) it uses a `StringBuilder` for normal String addition.

```
 url = new URL(strUrl.append(strKey).toString()); // There is nothing wrong with this.
```

But it is (functionally) identical to

```
 url = new URL(strUrl + strKey);
```

Prior to Java 1.5, `StringBuffer` was used.

Comment: The OP says he's looping, and since he/she isn't replacing `strUrl`, that implies reuse. So not functionally the same, and it's more efficient to use the `StringBuilder` than concatenation. But the question lacks sufficient information to be sure.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Perhaps. But OP doesn't mention resetting it either... hence my assumption.

Comment: That's what I mean. The OP doesn't mention resetting it, but does say he/she's looping. But as it's yet another bloomin' ask-and-run, I guess we won't know for a while. ***sigh***